# Check if input is only alphabets in javascript using IF ELSE statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field for which I need to make sure the input is only and only characters from the alphabet, with no:

- numbers
- special characters
- number + alphabet combinations

I want to do this using if else statement only. So far the code is:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform"  onsubmit="return check();" >
    <input class="input" type="text" name="firstname">
```

And JavaScript is:

```
function check() {
    var x = document.forms["myform"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == ""){
        myform.action="firstnameerror.html";}
    if (isNaN(x)) {
        myform.action="lastname.html";     
    } else { 
        myform.action="firstnameerror1.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use regex?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with/good at regex at the moment, hoping for a simpler solution

Comment: @Sophia111 Check out my answer: it uses regex, but it is a simple condition.

Comment: Does `if (typeof x == "string" && /^[A-z]*$/.test(x)) { ... }` count?

Comment: Does `naïve` contain special characters? Is famous mathematician `Gauß` part of your alphabet?

Comment: Note that `x` will never be `null`.

Comment: Tried out regex, wasn't so bad after all :) Thanks guys!

Comment: I put off regex for months when I first started learning javascript and now that I know it I wish I had taken the half hour to learn it early on. It seemed really complicated so I put it off but its the most simple and concise solution for the problems it solves. Good luck!

Comment: @hsiung haha that sounds just like me! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it using regular expressions ([`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)), specifically with the [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function:

```
if(/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(x))
    // code to throw error
```

This will run the code to throw an error if any non-alphabetic character is contained in `x`.

Comment: @Sophia111 If this works for you, feel free to accept this answer by clicking the green check mark next to it to show the community that it helped you.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! If I want to add in a if x== null condition, should i just add an else if statement?

Comment: @Sophia111 If you have different code to handle a null input, then yes, put it in an `else if` statement. If you want the same error handling code, then you can put it in the same conditional statement.